# How do you fix the command-not-found issue on Ubuntu 10.04?

Tags: ubuntu-10.04

I type some command which does not exist at the terminal and I get:

```
$ asd
/usr/bin/python: can't find '__main__.py' in '/usr/share/command-not-found'
```

How do I fix the above to display the correct error message?  The Ubuntu version I'm using is 10.04, 2.6.32-22

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See [this](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/bash/+bug/561046) bug. You can try the workaround listed or reinstall `command-not-found` and `command-not-found-data`.

Comment: Well that was some easy reputation for a Google search.

Comment: Or remove them... personally I can't stand the added delay when I've just made a simple typo!